# How to verify which vender sold my android app?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have developed an android app which is paid, now i want to sell my app. I have few vendors who will sell for me, I want to validate which vendor sold how many. How can i do it through my app.

Answer (score 0):

To help you start with, I think you need this official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#managed) for you to understand well the concept.

> The In-app Billing API makes it easier for you to integrate In-app
>   Billing into your applications. The In-app Billing API supports a
>   synchronous purchase flow, APIs to let you easily track ownership of
>   consumable goods, and local caching of in-app purchase data.

To [manage in-app products](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#managed):

> Managed in-app products are items that have their ownership
>   information tracked and managed by Google Play. When a user purchases
>   a managed in-app item, Google Play Stores the purchase information for
>   each item on a per-user basis. This enables you to later query Google
>   Play at any time to restore the state of the items a specific user has
>   purchased. This information is persistent on the Google Play servers
>   even if the user uninstalls the application or if they change devices.
>
> If you are using the In-app Billing API, you can also consume managed
>   items within your application. You would typically implement
>   consumption for items that can be purchased multiple times (such as
>   in-game currency, fuel, or magic spells). Once purchased, a managed
>   item cannot be purchased again until you consume the item, by sending
>   a consumption request to Google Play. To learn more about in-app
>   product consumption, see [Consuming Items](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume).